# Get global option in Rcpp

Tags: r, rcpp

I want to get the value of an option (e.g. `"width"`) inside Rcpp. I tried:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
int test_option() {

  Environment base("package:base");
  Function get_option = base["getOption"];
  return get_option("width");
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
int test_option2() {

  Environment base("package:base");
  Function get_option = base["options"];
  List l_width = get_option("width");
  return l_width[1];
}
```

The first function does not compile and the second one crashes the session.

Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why the code isn't working is because there is too much reliance on Rcpp's automagic conversion to *R*. You will need to create an intermediary step. *Recall* that *R* does not have a concept of the scalar `int` data type.

Let's look at the type being returned using Rinternal macros `Rf_type2char(TYPEOF(x))`

c.f.

```
#include<Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void test_option() {

  Rcpp::Environment base("package:base");
  Rcpp::Function get_option = base["getOption"];
  Rcpp::Rcout << Rf_type2char(TYPEOF(get_option("width")));
}
```

This gives:

```
test_option()
# integer
```

From there, add back in the return type:

```
#include<Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::IntegerVector  get_width() {

  Rcpp::Environment base("package:base");
  Rcpp::Function get_option = base["getOption"];
  Rcpp::IntegerVector out = get_option("width");

  return out;
}
```

Output:

```
get_width()
# [1] 155
```

Answer (score 3):

### test_option

Your first function would work if you wrote it like this:

```
SEXP test_option() {
```

or this:

```
IntgerVector test_option() {
```

### test_option2

Regarding the second function in your question, in the comments you write that your objective is to convert the SEXP to an `int` so in that case, if `s` is a `SEXP` holding an integer then `as<int>(s)` or `INTEGER(s)[0]` is an `int`. This is as opposed to an `IntegerVector`.   If you really meant to write that you want an `IntegerVector` then replace each of the three occurrences of `int` below with `IntegerVector`.

Place the code below in myOption.cpp in current directory and follow instructions in first line.

```
// To run: library(Rcpp); sourceCpp("myOption.cpp")

#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
int myOption(CharacterVector x) {
  Environment base( "package:base" ) ;
  Function getOption = base["getOption"];
  SEXP s = getOption(x);
  int i = as<int>(s);
  return i;
}

/*** R
myOption("width")
*/
```

Comment: Nop, the problem here was to get the global option "width" as an `int` in C++.

Comment: OK. I have changed it to show how to get an int from a SEXP holding an integer.

Comment: Yes, this is what I do based on @coatless answer.

Comment: No, that is not what is shown there. What is shown there is the use of `IntegerVector` and that is not the same as `int`

Comment: What I meant is "based on @coatless answer, I was able to apply it to my problem by adding a solution similar to what you mention, i.e. using `as<IntegerVector>(width)[0]`".